# Fill in QtableView's bottom space with empty rows

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt

I have `QTableView`, and I want to fill its bottom space by adding empty rows:

- If there is no data in the `QTableView`, this last must be filled with *n*
  empty rows with `n = QTableView.height() / QTableView.rowHeight()`
- If there is `m` filled row(s) with empty space at the bottom (of the `QTableView`), we must add `n` empty rows to the `QTableView`, with `n = (QTableView.height() / QTableView.rowHeight()) - m`
- Else *DO NOTHING*

My real problem here, is when resizing the `QTableView` we must add / remove empty rows in a way that the TableView must remains filled (while there is no `ScrollBar`)

I am looking for a way to update the `QTableView` item as the its dimensions changes.

**Note:**

- When there is a `ScrollBar`, there is no need to add any empty rows.
- I did count the `QHeader` height while calculating the number of empty rows.
- You cannot get the current height of the `QTableView`, as `QTableView.height()` will not return the exact height *Unless you call it after the QTableView has been shown*

I really stumbled across this problem, and I didn't find any solution, I have some ideas but they don't seem to be practical.

### **Update:**

I have managed to make a good advancement in my code so far, but still not what I wanted.

The big problem, is when adding or removing rows, I don't know what approach should I consider for doing this.

This a sample code for my problem.

*Main class:*

```
import sys
from math import floor

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableView, QAbstractItemView

from modeltest import TestModel

DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 30


class App(QtGui.QApplication):
    """Main application class"""

    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        """Constructor for App"""
        super(App, self).__init__(sys_argv)

        self.tableView = QTableView()
        self.tableView.resize(500, 400)
        self.tableView.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)  # Fix QObject::startTimer error message.
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tableView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.tableView.installEventFilter(self)

        self.model = TestModel()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

        self.tableView.show()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Resize and source is self.tableView:
            totalRowsNumber = (self.tableView.height() - 31) / DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT
            if totalRowsNumber > self.model.tasksCount():
                emptyRowsToAdd = totalRowsNumber - self.model.tasksCount()
            else:
                emptyRowsToAdd = 0

            self.model.emptyRowCount = floor(emptyRowsToAdd)

        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Model class:*

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class TestModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """The model associated with tasks table view"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor for TestModel"""
        super(TestModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__tasks = [['Task 1', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 2', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 3', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 4', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 5', 141546123, 80]]
        # self.__tasks = [[]]
        self.__header = ['Task', 'Timestamp', 'Status']
        self.__empty_row_count = 0

    @property
    def emptyRowCount(self):
        return self.__empty_row_count

    @emptyRowCount.setter
    def emptyRowCount(self, n):
        self.reset()    # reset model data.
        self.__empty_row_count = n

    def tasksCount(self):
        if len(self.__tasks) == 1 and self.__tasks[0] == []:
            return 0
        return len(self.__tasks)

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.tasksCount() + self.__empty_row_count

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.__header) + 1

    def flags(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        if row >= self.tasksCount():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if row < self.tasksCount() and column < len(self.__header):
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.__tasks[row][column]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if section < len(self.__header):
                    return self.__header[section]
```

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems to me that I have found an acceptable answer, I hope it's good, but for sure there is a better one.

Still, I did use the same code above along with some core changes.

**Note:**

- You can test adding or removing rows by pressing `Return` or `Delete` buttons.

*Main class*

```
import sys
from math import floor

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QEvent
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableView, QAbstractItemView

from modeltest import TestModel

DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT = 30


class App(QtGui.QApplication):
    """Main application class"""

    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        """Constructor for App"""
        super(App, self).__init__(sys_argv)

        self.tableView = QTableView()
        self.tableView.resize(500, 400)
        self.tableView.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)  # Fix QObject::startTimer error message.
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tableView.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tableView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.tableView.installEventFilter(self)

        self.model = TestModel()
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

        self.tableView.show()

    def setScrollBarVisibility(self, emptyRowCount):
        if emptyRowCount > 0:
            self.tableView.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        else:
            self.tableView.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Resize and source is self.tableView:
            totalRowNumber = (self.tableView.height()) / DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT
            self.model.updateRows(floor(totalRowNumber))
            self.setScrollBarVisibility(self.model.emptyRowCount())
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                self.model.addRow()
                self.setScrollBarVisibility(self.model.emptyRowCount())
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete:
                self.model.delRow()
                self.setScrollBarVisibility(self.model.emptyRowCount())

        return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Model class*

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class TestModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """The model associated with tasks table view"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor for TestModel"""
        super(TestModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__tasks = [['Task 1', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 2', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 3', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 4', 141546123, 80],
                        ['Task 5', 141546123, 80]]
        # self.__tasks = [[]]
        self.__header = ['Task', 'Timestamp', 'Status']
        self.__empty_row_count = 0
        self.__total_row_count = 0  # Max visible rows.

    def updateRows(self, n):
        self.__total_row_count = n
        if n > self.tasksCount():  # If the view has an empty space.
            self.__empty_row_count = n - self.tasksCount()
        else:
            self.__empty_row_count = 0

        self.reset()  # Reset the view, results to call rowCount method.

    def emptyRowCount(self):
        return self.__empty_row_count

    def tasksCount(self):
        if len(self.__tasks) == 1 and self.__tasks[0] == []:
            return 0
        return len(self.__tasks)

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.tasksCount() + self.__empty_row_count
        # Data rows + empty rows.

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.__header) + 1
        # headers + the last stretched column

    def flags(self, index):
        row = index.row()
        if row >= self.tasksCount():  # If it's an empty row.
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled  # Non selectable.

        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if row < self.tasksCount() and column < len(self.__header):
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.__tasks[row][column]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if section < len(self.__header):
                    return self.__header[section]

    def addRow(self):

        success = self.__tasks.append(['Task x', 141546123, 80])
        if self.__empty_row_count > 0:
            self.__empty_row_count -= 1
        self.reset()  # Update the view.

        return success

    def delRow(self):
        if self.__tasks:
            self.__tasks = self.__tasks[:-1]
            if self.__empty_row_count == 0:  # If the visible view was full before the deleting.
                if self.__total_row_count - self.tasksCount() == 1:  # If the view didn't remain full.
                    self.__empty_row_count += 1
            else:
                self.__empty_row_count += 1
            self.reset()  # Update the view.
            return True
```